# Product attributes and variations in Woocommerce Product Bundles

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On our site we are using WooCommerce with [Woocommerce product bundle plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/). I have a bit of a special case I'm afraid.

On our site we are selling lambs meat. There are several products of course and a lots of them are sold as a stand alone product and in a product bundle as well. There is one special bundle, we call it "for singles". A collection of the same products are added to the bundle, we just added smaller portions. For instance a portion of 250 grams instead of 500 grams.

The standalone product is 500 grams. The 250 grams version exists only in the "Package for singles". I do not want the 250 grams version visible in the shop or search results to be sold separately. At first we added two distinct products: a 250 grams version and a 500 grams version.

We added the 500 grams version to a couple of other bundles and we show it on the product pages as a stand alone product.

Working on SEO I learned that it is not done to add pages, posts or products with the same description as it will lead to a "Duplicate COntent" vote on Google and harm our rankings.

So what I want to achieve is this:

the 500 grams version shown as a single, stand alone product 
the 500 grams version in a couple of bundles 
the 250 grams version in only the "singles" bundle.

The single product page for the 500 grams version must be displayed as a "normal" single product without variations. So, no attributes and no pull down menu to select the options.

A checkbox whether or not the variations has to be displayed on the single product page should be great (I think).

Working with the settings for Attributes and Variations for more than a day now I realized I need some help. 
I've read up on a bunch of posts and tutorials but no avail.

Please advice

PS. I can't give you credentials for the live site because I don't want to interrupt anyting. But you can view the pages at https://lokaallamsvlees.nl. The site I am working for development purposes is on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen to keep both product variations and set the a canonical url at the small variation of the product. This way I avoid the duplicate content issue in Google and that was what it was all about.